# Where should I be defining and setting these styles

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, datatrigger

In the illustration below you can see a custom control that I'm currently creating with a view to learning as much as I can about the whole process of control creation.

[image]

Currently I'm trying to both simplify the xaml by effectively refactoring repetitive style elements out into a separate style and achieve a disabled look for images when the buttons in which they are situated are disabled.

In the xaml below you can see both the button style I've created and the data trigger for the image.  In theory both are being applied to the second button on the left, but quite clearly they aren't being.

I think that the basic style definitions are correct but it may be that they are in the incorrect place.  Can anyone advise as to what it is that I'm currently doing wrong.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewToLearn.WpfControls">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UIElement}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsEnabled}"
                         Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Opacity"
                        Value="0.2"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="4" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:VtlDataNavigator}">


        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:VtlDataNavigator}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                BorderThickness="0">
                            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                                <Image Source="/ViewToLearn.WpfControls;component/Resources/Images/button_rounded_blue_first24.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button> <!-- This is the button that should be influenced by the style and trigger defined above, but clearly it isn't -->
                        <Button IsEnabled="False">
                            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                                <Image Source="/ViewToLearn.WpfControls;component/Resources/Images/button_rounded_blue_previous24.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=RecordIndex,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 IsReadOnly="True"
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 Margin="4" />
                        <TextBlock Text="of"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Margin="4" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RecordCount,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Margin="4" />
                        <Button BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                BorderThickness="0">
                            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                                <Image Source="/ViewToLearn.WpfControls;component/Resources/Images/button_rounded_blue_next24.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second button has `IsEnabled="false"`
That makes the difference.

But if you want the background to be the same for all buttons, enabled or not, you have to got in the **triggers**.

The best way to generate the default style and template with triggers is to put a dummy/test button in a window, right click on it, Edit Template/Edit a copy.
VS will generate much code. You 'll see inside the "full" template" of the button + the triggers.

Inside there is a trigger for **different appearance when disabled** :

```
<Setter Property="Template" >
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
            <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <!-- ... -->
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="#FF838383"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

It's that template you can take inspiration from to update your style (without trigger when disabled):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
        Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
        Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
        Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
        Value="4" />
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <!-- no trigger int he template -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Notes regarding your code because it seems you are eager to learn :

1. Don't have to set Background, BorderThickness, BorderBrush for every button, it is already done in your `Button` style
2. The `StackPanel` around every `Image` is the same and can be put inside the template around the `ContentPresenter` tag
3. If `VtlDataNavigator` is a `Usercontrol`, you can put all the content of `<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:VtlDataNavigator}">` inside the `<UserControl>` tag.
   It makes the control more reusable (don't have to provide the template in every Window for the control)

Regards

Comment: Emmanuel, thank you for your comprehensive answer.  Regarding your points at the bottom, I know That I shouldn't need to set the properties for each button, that's why I want a style, but on the one button that in theory it should be set to it wasn't being applied.  This started out life as a user control, now I want to turn it into a custom control, both to learn how to do it and because it should be more reusable.  I suspect I might have been better starting this in Blend rather than visual studio, but vs I know, blend I don't.  I shall now work through your code and report back.

Comment: Here is my code trying to reproduce what you shown : http://1drv.ms/1ML5iZv. It should help. As far as you don't go in animation and don't need sample data, Blend is not really necessary.